# delete exact string from a large file?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have data in the following form in a file:

```
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/here>   <http://purl.uniprot.org/here/unipot/purl>
    <http://purl.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q196Y7>        <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/annotation>
```

I want to remove all "http://purl.uniprot.org" which are within the angular brackets. Such that the output which I get is

```
    <here>   <here/unipot/purl>
    <uniprot/Q196Y7>        <core/annotation>
```

I tried to do so using vi's replace command. But it turned out to be quite slow as my file is of 1TB. Is there a more efficient way to do the same using linux/python

I know I can use sed but sed find's patterns and deletes them whereas I want to delete the exact contents

Comment: If you have one with of 1TB then you are likely doing something *wrong*

Comment: A find/replace in a 1tb file? That could take DAYS

Comment: I think you mixed up TB with MB

Answer (score 1):

This should work from command-line:

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/purl.uniprot.org\///g' /path/to/filename
```

You can try first without `-i` argument to see the output in your console.

Comment: This will substitute anywhere, not just within brokets, though. As a partial remedy, maybe use `s%<http://purl\.uniprot\.org/%<%g` instead. (The beef here is to substitute `<http...` with `<` but I couldn't resist cleaning up the regex, too.)

Answer (score 1):

[As Radu Rădeanu said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19677150/34088), `sed` is a good tool for replacing strings in files since it works on streams instead of trying to load the whole file into memory.

But `sed` uses regular expressions and in your case (1TB of input data), this might be too slow. Unix tools can often handle files of arbitrary size and they are surprisingly efficient but corner cases might be too much.

If you need to optimize the process, here are a few pointers:

1. Split the huge file into smaller ones. For example, if this is a log file, create a single file per day instead of concatenating everything into one huge file. That way, you can strip the string **once** in each daily file.
2. Write a small C program that searches for the exact string (instead of using a regexp). You can then use optimizations like [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) to get a huge performance boost. You should also consider using memory-mapped I/O.

Comment: Unless you are a world-class programmer, I doubt your homegrown C program can outperform `sed`. Just make sure you don't write a sloppy regex.

Comment: Well, I have 120K so maybe I am :-) That said, for files as large as this, using a memory mapped approach with a static string pattern will be much faster, especially when you have a CPU that supports string operations. But as I also said, do this "if you need to optimize"

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by **"But it turned out to be quite"** ? quite what?
If it's me , vi is just a very good tool.run this command:

```
:s/http:\/\/purl.uniprot.org\//g
```

Comment: With a very large file, vi is a bit slow :-)